# Object Arrays in Azure Table Storage

Tags: arrays, azure, insert

I'm trying to build a simple Mobile Service on Azure and I'm having some problems while inserting my information. Right now, I've got two classes in my model, User and Car. A User has an AccountID, a Name (all these Strings) and an Array of Car. A Car has a Plate, a Color and a Model (all these Strings).

I'm serializing the User object correctly to JSON and when I try to do request.execute() it throws an error that says "The value of property 'cars' is of type object which is not supported". I know that only string, number, bool and date are suppported.

What I'd like to do, is to have two separate tables, one for users and another one for cars, and somehow establish a relationship between them. This is the script I've written so far

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    if(item.accountID !== user.userId){
        request.respond(statusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED,
        "Unauthorized user");
    } else {
        if(item.cars.length){
            var tableCars = tables.getTable('cars');
            populateTable(tableCars, request, item.cars);
        }
        request.execute();
    }       
}

function populateTable(table, request, array){
    var index = 0;

    var insertNext = function(){
        if(index < array.length){
            var toInsert = array[index];
            table.insert(toInsert, {
                success: function(){
                    index++;
                    insertNext();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    insertNext();
}
```

At this point I've got several problems. If I leave it this way, it crashes because items.cars is an Array of Car (an object for JS) but I do want to have here some kind of id to find cars that belong to this User in its table. Maybe I should add some kind to 'owner' to Car, but I'm not sure, my knowledge of databases is somehow poor.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Azure table storage does not support relational tables.  Furthermore, ATS does not support storing of strongly typed child objects as a part of parent entities.  ATS is a key-value entity-based table storage.  It only supports basic data types like string, date, double, boolean, etc.

If you want to store complex objects in ATS (complex, meaning objects that contain other objects), it is suggested that you should serialize the child objects as strings rather then objects, when storing the data and de-serialize the strings back into objects during retrieval.

Alternatively, you can get very fancy with your Row/PartitionKeys and store Parent object and child objects as different entities within the same PartitionKey - and when reading the values back, reconstruct the hierarchy.

Comment: I've been researching the whole day about Partition/RowKeys and you're right, that's what I want but I've found no code on how to set them, only things about people asking how to edit them and if it was posible